# Double indefinite integrals!

Tags: calculus

How to evaluate this indefinite integral? I tried by polar coordinate or substitution, but I couldn't go through it. Is there any help please?

$$\int e ^{-(x^4 + y^4)} dxdy $$

Comment: Really surprised if this has a closed form, on either a disc or a square region. What is the source of this problem?

Comment: were you interested in the definite integral or only the indefinite integral?

Comment: I'm looking for an indefinite one and if possible analytical one. I mean not a fancy one but intuitive approach ( like changing to polar coordinate ).

Comment: @John: what do you mean by an indefinite integral on $\mathbb{R}^2$? Changing to polar coordinates, one would need to know the domain of integration first.

Comment: The domain is R^2, and for polar r(0 to infinity),(theta 0 to 2pi). I mean if there is a way to solve in polar. I tried, but I stuck in exponential integration to the power of -r^4(sin theta - cos theta)^2 and (rdrdtheta).

Answer (score 3):

The definite integral over the entire plane can be computed in terms of the Gamma function:
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^4-y^4}\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty  e^{-x^4}e^{-y^4}\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^4}\,\mathrm{d}x\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-y^4}\,\mathrm{d}y\\
&=\left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^4}\,\mathrm{d}x\right)^2\\
&=\left(2\int_0^\infty e^{-x^4}\,\mathrm{d}x\right)^2\\
&=4\left(\int_0^\infty e^{-x^4}\,\mathrm{d}x\right)^2\\
&=4\left(\frac14\int_0^\infty e^{-u}u^{-3/4}\,\mathrm{d}u\right)^2\\
&=\frac14\Gamma\left(\frac14\right)^2
\end{align}
$$
The indefinite integral in two dimensions is a function of the domain, not like the anti-derivative in one dimension, where the domain is usually an interval. I am not sure what you are looking for when you ask for the indefinite integral on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Would the downvoters care to comment? If you have some answer for an indefinite integral on $\mathbb{R}^2$, please enlighten us, rather than leaving unjustified downvotes.

Comment: Many thanks, and is there any way to calculate it analytically?

Comment: @John: By analytically, do you mean a closed form not involving the Gamma function? If so, then I don't think there is.

Comment: @John: in the integral above, we did not need to use polar coordinates; the integrals are already separated. All we need to do is to use $e^{-x^4-y^4}=e^{-x^4}e^{-y^4}$ then the double integral is simply the square of a single integral. The single integral is simply a Gamma integral after the change of variables $u=x^4$.

Comment: robjohn, it sometimes seems that people will downvote anything that does not appear to directly answer the initial question, no matter how wrongheaded the initial question was. I used to automatically answer the question that ought to have been asked, lately i am just as likely to leave it alone or vote to close as unclear.

Comment: @robjohn: It appears we'd both been the victims of serial downvoting about one hour ago today.

Comment: Even if the integrand is trivially integrable (e.g., $f(x,y) = x^2 y^2$ for all $(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2$), we would have considerable difficulty expressing $$\int\!\!\int_R f(x,y) \, dx \, dy$$ in terms of some general region $R$.

Comment: @Lucian: it seems that the script agreed with you.

Answer (score 0):

$\displaystyle\int_0^\infty e^{-x^n}dx=\Big(\!\tfrac1n\!\Big)!\quad$ However, the indefinite integral does not possess a closed form expression.

See [Liouville's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_%28differential_algebra%29) and the [Risch algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risch_algorithm) for more details.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid Gamma function, and solve it more pedestrian way it I can! What if I try approximation way? Is there a more accurate of that? I mean which method is the best.

Comment: @John: Approximation for the *indefinite* integral ? Or for the *definite* one ? If the latter, should I assume you mean numerical approximation ? If so, then the upper integration limit can safely be anything in between $2$ and $3$, since in the former case the error is in the order of $10^{-9}$, and in the latter case, $10^{-38}$, for the *simple* integral, and the square of that for the double integral.